# Automatically log-out Inactive Users on non-enterprise Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit box used as a shared resource between all the members of my family.  Fast user switching is enable, and often quite useful.  However, that means the Screen Saver's "On Resume, display login screen" does a fast user switch, not a logoff.  So, eventually, everyone is logged into the PC, with background users "stealing" RAM and (I assume) CPU cycles from the person actually using the machine.

What I want to do is force a 'session' to logoff after a lengthy idle time, say 2 hours.

Google'ing 'auto logoff windows 7' presents a vast array of choices, most of which seem to disagree with each other.

Anyone know a straightforward way to set an auto-logoff policy across all users on a single Windows 7 box?

Comment: If you haven't already, check the solution given in this thread: [automatic logout after inactivity/idle](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d358382c-e91b-4e91-a1e8-04c53cfd91ce/automatic-logout-after-inactivityidle)

Answer (score 0):

If you are an administrative user you can manually logout users....

1. start the task manager
2. AT the bottom left, press "show processes for all users"
3. Select the Users tab to show all the local users logged on
4. Select the user to be logged off and press the LOGOFF button at the bottom right

Comment: Sure, that works manually, do that all the time.  I'm looking for an automated solution.

Comment: There are third party solutions for autologout which you'd have to use since there are no policies for non-enterprise situations.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how comfortable you are with third party applications check this one out:

http://www.grimadmin.com/staticpages/index.php/ss-operations

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.